# angular img src not updating on object property

Tags: html, angular, blob

To display an image in an image gallery I have to download a Blob through the a REST API. I have multiple images being rendered by an *ngFor loop as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let galleryItem of galleryItems">
   <img [src]="galleryItem.blobUrlThumb">
</div>
```

However, when my Blob URL gets written to the galleryItem object, the image src stubbornly stays stuck on null and does not update.

```
// Component code example
galleryItems: GalleryItem[] = [galleryItem];
this.apiService.download(`/x/y/${galleryItem.id}`).subscribe((blob: Blob) => {
   galleryItem.blobUrlThumb = this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
});
```

If I do the same with a local variable in the component everything works fine:

```
<div *ngFor="let galleryItem of galleryItems">
   <img [src]="blobUrlThumb">
</div>
```

I would prefer saving the Blob URL in the GalleryItem object. Why is the update not taking place on said object?

Comment: Can you share component code?

Comment: You probably have a problem with detecting changes after receiving your api response, would you mind posting that part of your component?

Comment: you always change your object galleryItem.blobUrlThumb in your subscribe, so your object always change simply console.log it. I did the same (using local variable) and added it to an array (pushing it if the generated blob is not null).

Comment: @JensHabegger I posted some of my component code. I'm simply subscribing and setting the `galleryItem.blobUrlThumb variable` in there.

Comment: @JensHabegger, this is not an issue with the change detection. Changing `galleryItem.blobUrlThumb` will not have an effect on the array it was used to initialize. As a result triggering the change detection manually will be of no value

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is to push the blob in an array. `galleryItem.blobUrlThumb` is `null` because you don't have that object in your array.
You don't have the blob data in your array that you're iterating over inside your component

With this initialization:

```
galleryItems: GalleryItem[] = [galleryItem];
```

You will need to reset the data before pushing the new blob data into it. Given the method in which you're subscribing to the observable, it will look like:

```
 subscribeMethod() : void {
     // reset the array 
     // otherwise you will iterate over objects that are null
     this.galleryItems= [];
     this.apiService.download(`/x/y/${galleryItem.id}`).subscribe((blob: Blob) => { 
       // and you can push the new data
       galleryItem.blobUrlThumb = this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
       this.galleryItems.push(galleryItem.blobUrlThumb);
      });
   }
```

or the other way, would simply to create a new array that you will use to push the blob data.

Comment: the `galleryItems` array is there already. I'm simply modifying an object that is part of that array. Since the object is already there, I don't see why I should have to push it again (or do you mean remove it, and re-push it?)

Comment: Unless you push it to the array, the `src` will always be null. And that makes sense, because initially there is nothing in your array. And when you subscribe to the value sent by the observable, you need to push that value to your array. Do you have only one item in your array ? Since your array already contains some data, you will need to reset the array

Comment: Check out my edited question. The `galleryItem` object is already in the array, before I even try to get the Blob URL. I'm simply modifying one of its properties when I get the URL.

Comment: I saw the edited question. Since you already have some initial value in the array, you cannot push. This is why I am saying that you will need to reset the array. Why not simply create a new array where you could push your `galleryItem.blobUrlThumb` ?

Comment: _I would prefer saving the Blob URL in the GalleryItem object. Why is the update not taking place on said object?_
Creating a new Array is simply a workaround for a problem I can't explain. If I have a text input, bound to `galleryItem.title`, and change this variable programmatically the value will update automatically in the DOM. Why is this not happening with the [src] attribute?

Comment: The `galleryItems` and `galleryItem` are two differents variables. You have simply initialize the array `galleryItems` with `galleryItem`. You cannot modify the second variable and think that the change will happen in the array. This is simple javaScript. What you're talking about is the binding that angular does between the template and the component. That is not a workaround as you suggest. You simply need to change your logic, sorry there is no way around